MYSQL query for the below result
Every transaction in Table A has related transactions.
The related transactions are shown in Table B.
Table C has the corresponding type name.
Need to pull all transactions where Type Payment_GP does not exist.
For example transaction with ID 1 has Rel_ID D which is Payment_GP. So any related transactions for 1 should not be returned.
Table A
ID
1
2
A
B
C
D
E
F

Table B
ID  Rel_ID
1   A
1   B
1   C
1   D
2   E
2   F

Table C
ID  Type
A   Payment_Adv
B   Payment_Clr
c   Payment_A
D   Payment_GP
E   Payment_Adv
F   Payment_Clr

Expected Output:
ID  Rel_ID  Type
2   G   Payment_Adv
2   H   Payment_Clr

My query is not returning the output as expected.
SELECT A.id,
       B.Rel_ID,
       C.Type
FROM Table_A A
INNER JOIN Table_B B ON A.ID = B.ID
INNER JOIN Table_C C ON B.Rel_ID = C.ID
WHERE NOT EXISTS
    (SELECT 1
     FROM Table_C C1
     WHERE C1.ID = C.ID
       AND C1.Type IN ('Payment_GP'))
;


"Need to pull all transactions where Type Payment_GP does not exist.", and you query says:   WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT ..... IN ('Payment_Adv', 'Payment_Clr'))   Please clarify

You need at Table_B to remove the unwanted ids
CREATE TABLE Table_A (
  `ID` varchar(1)
);

INSERT INTO Table_A
  (`ID`)
VALUES
  ('1'),
  ('2'),
  ('A'),
  ('B'),
  ('C'),
  ('D'),
  ('E'),
  ('F');


Records: 8  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0


CREATE TABLE Table_B (
  `ID` INTEGER,
  `Rel_ID` VARCHAR(1)
);

INSERT INTO Table_B
  (`ID`, `Rel_ID`)
VALUES
  ('1', 'A'),
  ('1', 'B'),
  ('1', 'C'),
  ('1', 'D'),
  ('2', 'E'),
  ('2', 'F');


Records: 6  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0


CREATE TABLE Table_C (
  `ID` VARCHAR(1),
  `Type` VARCHAR(11)
);

INSERT INTO Table_C
  (`ID`, `Type`)
VALUES
  ('A', 'Payment_Adv'),
  ('B', 'Payment_Clr'),
  ('c', 'Payment_A'),
  ('D', 'Payment_GP'),
  ('E', 'Payment_Adv'),
  ('F', 'Payment_Clr');


Records: 6  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0


SELECT A.id,
       B.Rel_ID,
       C.Type
FROM Table_A A
INNER JOIN Table_B B ON A.ID = B.ID
INNER JOIN Table_C C ON B.Rel_ID = C.ID
WHERE NOT EXISTS    (SELECT 1
     FROM Table_B B1 
      INNER JOIN Table_C C1 ON B1.Rel_ID = C1.ID 
     WHERE B1.ID = A.id
       AND C1.`Type` IN ('Payment_GP'))




id
Rel_ID
Type




2
F
Payment_Clr


2
E
Payment_Adv



fiddle
